# 3750 failed post. Internal fixed?

Tags: cisco-3750

I have a 3750 manufactured in Feb of 2009, model number ws-3750-48ps-s V07. I'm consoled into it and when I power the switch, it boots (fans RPM) but no console display at all. The POE, stack, and speed lights are all froze green, and the duplex and stat lights are froze orange. I've been reading about these switched failing POST often, which I'm assuming is whats happening. Is there any internal fixes for this? I do not know any previous information as far as config goes or its previous life.

Comment: There is no internal fix if you can't get in. It sounds like you will need to contact Cisco TAC to have it replaced under warranty or SmartNet. We have used thousands of these devices, but have not really had any unusual failure rates.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure you are consoled in properly?
2. Cisco will replace the switch provided you are the original purchaser under the Limited lifetime warranty.  However, the terms of the LLW state for only 5 years from the end of manufacture date which unfortunately has passed.

[Duration of Hardware Warranty](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/general/warranty/English/LH2DEN__.html): As long as the original End User continues to own or use the Product. In the event of discontinuance of product manufacture, Cisco warranty support is limited to five (5) years from the announcement of discontinuance.

Answer (score 0):

This model of ws-3750-48ps-s isn't covered by Cisco anymore.

See http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3750-series-switches/end_of_life_notice_c51-574778.html

You could replace it with the still supported 3750x switches as this series is compatible with the old 3750-48 switch stack.